# When designing website is opening new tab as bad as a popup window

Tags: html, user-interface, mobile

My web application is mimicing the UI of my desktop application, flow is as follows

1. Select Task in browser window

[image]

2. Change any Options and then start

[image]

3. Show Progress in same browser window, the progress bar goess back to server every 5 seconds checking progress.

[image]

4. When task has completed we show report in new tab

[image]

and go back to Select task Window,

[image]

this is done by running following Javascript in progress page

window.open('/start','_self'); window.open('/reporturl','_blank');

This works fine on my PC but when trying on Safari on OSX and on Android phone and iPad one of two things happen

1. The progress page becomes the start page but the report page is not opened in tab
2. The Progress page becomes the report page

My question is does opening window in new tab with `_blank` have all the problems of using popup windows. If so should I modify my prcoess so that at stage 3 it just displays report page, and then add a back button or navigable footer to the report to allow user to get back to start page ?

Comment: Using window.open generally triggers the popup blocker when it is not directly connected to a user interaction (click). You could open the new tab right away when the user makes their selection, then it is less likely to get blocked.

Comment: window.open() is okay when just replacing existing window with _self ?, you mean open an empty tab when user selcts task and then later on put report on that tab ?

Comment: Don’t know, different popup blocker implementations might handle that differently. If you just want to change the current tab, then you don’t need window.open for that, assigning the new URL to location.href will do.

Comment: or do you think Im better off just not using mutliple tabs, on the devices Im testing on I havent knowing even installed a popup blocker.

Comment: Well that really depends on what exactly your app is supposed to achieve, and what UI behavior might make most sense for that. Maybe after the user selects a report, only show your progress bar - and then, when the process is finished, dynamically add a link/button that then opens the report in a new tab. For a link, target="_blank" would do, without any additional JavaScript; but even if you keep using window.open, at this point it should not be blocked, because the user just clicked.

Comment: @CBroe my starting point was mimicing the desktop app and this opens the report automatically in a browser  when the task has completed. But your suggestion of adding a button that user has to click would be okay I think, it certainly that sounds worth trying I will give it a go.

Comment: _"my starting point was mimicing the desktop app"_ - understandable approach/desire, and while that might work for certain scenarios/tasks, I often find that trying to “force” it too much can lead to a worse user experience. Multiple browser tabs work fine in a desktop browser - I always have all my tabs in sight in the tab bar, I see how many there are, ideally I can “identify” which contains what by the title already, etc. But on mobile that’s a different issue, you usually only see your current tab, and have to change the view to even get an overview of all open tabs.

Comment: And if the user is likely to start more than one task at a time, that would get even more confusing on mobile then, I’d imagine. Maybe implementing tabs yourself, while staying in one page, might be an alternative? Like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs (just as an example, doesn’t have to be bootstrap of course) - when the user starts a new task, you could add a new tab, show placeholder content or your progress bar inside it,

Comment: and then load the actual task result into the tab dynamically, when it is finished? You could even put the progress indicator into the tab title, so that the user can directly see which tasks have already finished.

Comment: Maybe you are overcomplicating  things the user only runs one task a time, so runs one task there will be two tabs, run another task would end up with three tabs (unless she closes Previous report). The report itself is a standalone html page (exactly the same as what is created by desktop app) and therefore i dont want to integrate this with progress bar etc. But I agree with you about forcing things so when you say on mobile can only see current tab it makes me think that maybe I should just replace progress page with report page and add back button to avid the complexity.

Comment: _“Maybe you are overcomplicating things”_ - yeah, just spit-balling here, what the “optimum” solution would be in the end depends on the specifics of course. But if generating that report takes a longer amount of time, some kind of progress indicator is still a good thing to have, if only just for the user to know, will this give me a result eventually, or has it “died” on me ...

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your interest , Ive added screenshots so it is clearer exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Is confusing, on my phone I have a 'Google' browser and a Google Chrome browser, Chrome does support tabs and works, the Google browser is not Chrome and does not seem to support tabs at all. I then installed Firefox and this also supports tabs but blocks report opening (as you suggested earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of some options you could use instead of new tab.

- **Modal with Ajax**
  -- With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it is posible to open [modal
  dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) they can be populated with html (or other data) fetched with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) (async). I am a big fan of these and use them all over my projects. Users will not be annoyed with pop-up warning messages, etc. Once the content is read (or whatever) the user can simply close the dialog. (If I had to make your app I would certainly implement this).

  Besides the jQuery dialogs, other modal/dialog scripts are out there. [Check out Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) if you like it modern.
- **Serve report as download**
  -- Depending on what the user can/will do with the report, it might be interesting to write the report page in a way that it sends back a .pdf file, or another type of file, as download. Loading the URL in a new tab will now always start a download. Triggering this from JS without user interaction might be a problem though (same as with pop-up / new tab). Adding a button to trigger the download on complete will solve this.

I know the question was about the use of tabs.. But try to avoid it. Browsers handle it all in their own way. And many users get confused when suddenly stuff is opening in tabs when they did not ask for it. In case of pop-ups, it is possible for users to turn them of or convert into opening a new tab from within the browser settings. If they have been fiddling with browser defaults, you'll have troubles of keeping the 'flow' of the app the same for all users (and cross browser).

Comment: Some useful ideas but your most important point was about not opening new tabs. This is in fact what I have done, the progress page is now replaced by the report page in the same window, and the report page has a 'return to start' link, I think this simplification of flow is the bets approach for max compatability.